# Two variadic template arguments with the same size

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I wanna implement a Print function which works this:

```
Print<1, 3>("Hello", "World");
```

and I hope that it will print "Hello" one time and "World" 3 times.I wonder how to implement it.
Below is my stupid code, of course it failed when compiling:

```
template <unsigned int n, unsigned int ...n_next,
          typename T, typename ...Ts>
void Print(T & t, Ts & ... ts)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << t << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    Print<n_next..., ts...>(ts...);
}

template <unsigned int n, typename T>
void Print(T & t)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << t << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: No code is stupid code :( :C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see four problems in your code

(1) the recursive call

```
Print<n_next..., ts...>(ts...);
```

is wrong because you have to use `Ts...` types in template argument list, not `ts...` values

```
Print<n_next..., Ts...>(ts...);
```

or, better (because permit a trick I explain next) without explicating the types

```
Print<n_next...>(ts...);
```

(2) is better if you receive as **const** references the values

```
template <unsigned int n, unsigned int ...n_next,
          typename T, typename ...Ts>
void Print(T const & t, Ts ... ts)
// ..........^^^^^
```

otherwise you can't call `Print()` with constant values as follows

```
Print<1u, 3u>(1, "world");
```

(3) better use unsigned value for indexes in `for` loops because you have to test they with unsigned values (minor problem)

```
// ..VVVVVVVV
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

(4) you have to place the ground case for `Print()` (the one that receive only a value) **before** the recursive case.

I suggest to substitute they with

```
template <typename = void>
void Print ()
 { }
```

because, this way, all prints are done in recursive version an you don't need to repeat equal code in two different function (but you have to call `Print<n_next...>(ts...);` the recursion.

So I propose to modify your code as follows

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename = void>
void Print ()
 { }

template <unsigned int n, unsigned int ...n_next,
          typename T, typename ...Ts>
void Print(T const & t, Ts ... ts)
{
    for(auto i = 0u; i < n; i++)
     {
       std::cout << t << " ";
     }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    Print<n_next...>(ts...);
}

int main ()
 {
   Print<1u, 3u>("hello", "world");
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

This will make it:

```
template <unsigned int n, typename T>
void Print(T&& t)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << std::forward<T>(t) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <std::size_t Idx1, std::size_t... Idx, class T, class... Ts>
void Print(T&& t, Ts&& ... ts) {
    Print<Idx1>(std::forward<T>(t));

    using expand = int[];
    (void)expand{(Print<Idx>(std::forward<Ts>(ts)), 0) ...};
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to use two template-arguments for the first one really. Also, the second should probably also be able to handle no arguments… And there is something to be said to be able to print temporaries.

Answer (score 1):

I also propose a completely different solution that avoid at all recursion and `for()` loops.

It simulate template folding in C++14 in initialization of an unused C-style array.

First the main `Print()`, that expand the variadic lists calling a `Print_h()` helper function, passing to it the values and list (index sequence) correspinding to numbers of iteration for every value

```
template <std::size_t ... Ns, typename ... Ts>
void Print (Ts ... ts)
 {
   using unused=int[];

   (void)unused { 0, (Print_h(std::make_index_sequence<Ns>{}, ts), 0)... };
 }
```

Next the helper function that uses the same trick for multiple printing

```
template <std::size_t ... Is, typename T>
void Print_h (std::index_sequence<Is...>, T const & t)
 {
   using unused=std::size_t[];

   (void)unused { 0, (std::cout << t << " ", Is)... };

   std::cout << std::endl;
 }
```

The following is the full compiling C++14 example

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t ... Is, typename T>
void Print_h (std::index_sequence<Is...>, T const & t)
 {
   using unused=std::size_t[];

   (void)unused { 0, (std::cout << t << " ", Is)... };

   std::cout << std::endl;
 }

template <std::size_t ... Ns, typename ... Ts>
void Print (Ts ... ts)
 {
   using unused=int[];

   (void)unused { 0, (Print_h(std::make_index_sequence<Ns>{}, ts), 0)... };
 }

int main ()
 {
   Print<1u, 3u>("hello", "world");
 }
```

If you can't use C++14 but only C++11, isn't difficult to develop substitutes for `std::make_index_sequence` and `std::index_sequence` (both available only from C++14).

Obviously in C++17 you can use template folding simplifying the functions as follows

```
template <std::size_t ... Is, typename T>
void Print_h (std::index_sequence<Is...>, T const & t)
 {    
   ((std::cout << t << " ", (void)Is), ...);

   std::cout << std::endl;
 }

template <std::size_t ... Ns, typename ... Ts>
void Print (Ts ... ts)
 { (Print_h(std::make_index_sequence<Ns>{}, ts), ...); }
```

Comment: The OP tagged the question as [tag:c++14] initially, was an edit that removed it, don't know why... +1 for the sequence version.

Comment: @Jans It was removed because the OP specifically said C++11, and some other editor edited it to 14. clearly conflicting

Comment: @Sombrero Chicken I see 

Comment: @Jans - Anyway create a C++11 substitute for `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence` isn't difficult (well... maybe a good one is not so simple)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code work by just swapping the declarations of the two overloads and removing the `ts...` template argument in the recursive call:

```
template <unsigned int n, typename T>
void Print(T & t)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << t << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <unsigned int n, unsigned int ...n_next,
          typename T, typename ...Ts>
void Print(T & t, Ts & ... ts)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << t << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    Print<n_next...>(ts...);
}
```

(also, be consistant with signedness)
[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/509bad5aeff0f0ce)

Furthermore, you don't need to duplicate the printing part, just call the other overload:

```
template <unsigned int n, typename T>
void Print(T & t)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << t << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <unsigned int n, unsigned int ...n_next,
          typename T, typename ...Ts>
void Print(T & t, Ts & ... ts)
{
    Print<n>(t);
    Print<n_next...>(ts...);
}
```

Alternatively, if you can use C++17 for fold expressions, you can do the following (use forwarding references and `std::forward` if you need to):

```
template<typename T>
void Print(unsigned int n, T& t)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << t << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template<unsigned int... Ns, typename... Ts>
void Print(Ts&... ts)
{
    (Print(Ns, ts), ...);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c0f84c11be73d08)

Comment: I don't approve the code duplication (actual printing cycle)

Comment: Why don't you call the non-variadic print in the variadic one instead of duplicating its body? o.O

Comment: @Zereges I figured I'd simply show how to fix OP's code. I added alternatives.